# MySQL Variable not working

Tags: mysql

I tried to learn about MySQL Variable and do command like this

```
SET @target=`name`;
SELECT @target FROM transaction_product LIMIT 10;
```

But it is error and said `Unknown column 'name' in 'field list'`
Why it is error, i'm sure there is column name on my field list

here is the screenshot of the table

[image: MySQL Table]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to use different quotes 'name' for assigning string to a variable and `` `name ``` for column names:

```
SET @target='name';
```

to get column value you can use `INTO` clause:

```
SELECT `name`
INTO @target
FROM transaction_product
LIMIT 1;
```

to get multiple rows in single variables you can use `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`name`)
INTO @target
FROM transaction_product
LIMIT 10;
```

to execute query dynamically:

```
SET @target='`name`';

SET @query1 = CONCAT('
    SELECT ',@target,'
    FROM transaction_product
    LIMIT 10'
    );
PREPARE stmt FROM @query1; EXECUTE stmt; DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: is that mean variable can't use for select field name? i see you hardcoding the `name` field...

Comment: you can't assign column name to variables and use that variable in select clause. for that you can use PREPARE stmt.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT @target:=`name` FROM transaction_product LIMIT 10;
```